# Benchmark Server Performance with Classic ASP & Disk I/O?

Tags: performance, asp-classic

Is there some way like a script we can run `n` times in a loop to benchmark classic ASP CPU computation time and disk I/O from server to server?  That is, run on a local workstation, then a local Pentium dev server with rotational disk, then a entry level production server with RAID 01, then a virtualized cloud production server, then a quad-core xeon server with SSDs, etc.  So we can see "how much faster" the servers are from one to the next.  The only tricky part is testing SQL and I/O testing.   Perhaps the script could compute at random and then write a 10gb file to disk or a series of 1gb files and then time how long it takes to create them, write them, copy/move them, read them in and calculate and MD5 on them and spit out the results to the client, say, in a loop of n times.  What we're trying to do is prove with a control set of code and tasks server performance from one machine to the next.

Answer (score 0):

**-- EDIT --**

Of course, as pointed out by *jbwebtech* below, VBS does indeed have its own `Timer()` function, which I had completely forgotten about.  And so...

Well you can just get the time before you run each process, run the process and then deduct it from the current time...

```vb
<%
Dim start
start = Timer()
'Run my process...
...
...
Response.Write(Timer()-start))
%>
```

It's perhaps not perfect, but it will give you back a fairly useful reading.  The 
result is a Double precision number<del>; the first part of the result is the number of days that have passed since you started, and the fractional part, obviously fractions of days.  You can work this out into time if you wish by dividing by the appropriate amounts (i.e. 24 hours in a day, 60 minutes in an hour, 1440 minutes in a day, 60 seconds in an hour, 86400 seconds in a day etc.).</del>  [The `Timer()` function](http://www.codefixer.com/codesnippets/vbscript_timer_function.asp) gives you the time in seconds and milliseconds taken to execute the code block.

Comment: ASP has a Timer() that returns milliseconds but that can't show me Compilation Time versus Disk I/O wait, etc.   I was hoping for something more granular in terms of the *tasks* being performed during n milliseconds.

Comment: To do this you'd need to hook the processes using system level calls.  [Will this help](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/79314/How-to-call-a-NET-DLL-from-a-VBScript)?